# C++: Syntax error C2061: Unexpected identifier

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors

What's wrong with this line of code?

bar foo(vector ftw);

It produces

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'vector'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try std::vector instead. Also, make sure you

```
#include <vector>
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably you forgot to include vector and/or import `std::vector` into the namespace.

Make sure you have:

```
#include <vector>
```

Then add:

```
using std::vector;
```

or just use:

```
bar foo(std::vector<odp> ftw);
```

Comment: damn, beat me by one second ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have:

`#include <vector>`

and

`using namespace std;` in your code?

`<vector>` defines the `std::vector` class, so you need to include it some where in your file.

since you're using `vector`, you need to instruct the compiler that you're going to import the whole `std` namespace (arguably this is not something you want to do), via `using namespace std;`

Otherwise vector should be defined as `std::vector<myclass>`

Answer (score 0):

try `std::vector<odp>` or `using std;`

Answer (score 0):

On its own, that snippet of code has no definition of `bar`, `vector` or `odp`. As to why you're not getting an error about the definition of `bar`, I can only assume that you've taken it out of context.

I assume that it is supposed to define `foo` as a function, that `vector` names a template and that it is supposed to define a parameter called `ftw` but in a declaration anything that is not actually being defined needs to have been declared previously so that the compiler knows what all the other identifiers mean.

For example, if you define new types as follows you get a snippet that will compile:

```
struct bar {};
struct odp {};
template<class T> struct vector {};

bar foo(vector<odp> ftw);
```